# Get fields of pydantic BaseModel as Literal

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

Basically I have a `BaseModel` that represents a database table.

Example:

```py
class DBTable(BaseModel):
  id: int
  name: str
  last_name: str
```

I now want to have a function that takes the `id`, `key` and new `value` and updates the database entry. And I want the `key` to be a `Literal` of the `BaseModel`.

Currently I am doing:

```py
def set_entry(id: int, key: Literal["name", "last_name"], value: str):
   ...
```

but I would prefer something more generic.
Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to update these fields in separate requests? You can do it in one request

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I don't want to update them all at once. I just want to have a function that I can use at multiple places in the code where I can set a field. And the `Literal` is there to help the linter for auto completion (and for me not always looking up how the fieldsnames are ;) )

Comment: I clarified my idea in the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
class UpdateSchema(BaseModel):
  id: int | None = None
  name: str | None = None
  last_name: str | None = None

def set_entry(id: int, update_data: UpdateSchema):
   update_fields_dict = update_data.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)
   for key, value in update_fields_dict.items():
       # update field with name `key`
       pass
       # In SQLAlchemy:
       # session.execute(
       #    update(ModelName).where(ModelName.id==id), update_fields_dict)
       # )
       # session.commit()
```

It will update only those fields, that you specify when create UpdateSchema object:

```
set_entry(id=1, update_data=UpdateSchema(name="123")) # Will update only name
```

Comment: That could be a solution, yes. But I think it adds some boilerplate to always create a class instance :/ I thought of calling the function like: `set_entry(id=1, key="name", value="123")` and basically having just a nice linter autocomplete on the `key` field.

Comment: This approach is useful when those `name` and `value` are coming from user's input. You can put this data into json and validate by using that model